# Getting undefined using new Map() in Class for counting occurences in array

Tags: javascript, class

I keep getting undefined with this class, please someone help me!
i have tried adding this.something to almost everything in the constructor, which shouldn't be neccesary and it still doesnt work (no big surprise there...), would really appreciate some help!

```
class Counter {
  constructor(text) {
    // TODO: build an internal Map of word => occurrences.
    this.text = text;
    const textArray = this.text.split(" ");
    const count = {};
    for (const word of textArray) {
      if (count[word]) {
        count[word] += 1;
      } else {
        count[word] = 1;
      }
    }
    this.map1 = new Map();
    for (const word of textArray) {
      this.map1.set(word, count[word]);
    }

  }


  occurrences(word) {
    // TODO: return the number of occurrences
    return this.map1.get(word);
  }
}
```

error:

```
Should be case-insensitive

    expect(received).toBe(expected)
    
    Expected value to be (using ===):
      1
    Received:
      undefined
    
    Difference:
    
      Comparing two different types of values. Expected number but received undefined.
      
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/01_counter.test.js:9:40)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5
```

and this is the test:

```
test("Should be case-insensitive", () => {
  const counter = new Counter("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit");
  expect(counter.occurrences("lorem")).toBe(1);
});
```

Comment: What exactly is undefined in your program? Please edit your question to include the error message and any relevant code snippets

Comment: just did, sorry i am new to posting questions on stack overflow!

Comment: if I'm understanding everything correctly, you try to `get` "hello" from your map, which isn't added obviously if you initialize your Counter class with "". The `get` method returns undefined if there is no entry for the provided key.

Answer (score 1):

If the key doesn't exist in the map, `occurrences()` needs to return `0`, because `get()` will return `undefined`.

```
  occurrences(word) {
    // TODO: return the number of occurrences
    return this.map1.get(word) || 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no key "hello" in Map, then this.map1.get("hello") will return undefined, not 0.

If you want to receive 0 in case there are no occurances, modify method

```
  occurrences(word) {
    // TODO: return the number of occurrences
    return this.map1.get(word) ?? 0;
  }
```

Comment: sorry maybe i wasnt specific enough, but i get undefined no matter the string or word i use, i edited the question so you can check, thanks anyway for the answer!

Comment: log the Map object to check if the entry really exists. As it was said multiple times, it returns `undefined` if the entry does not exist which is expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The test case you've supplied requires the `occurences()` function to return 0 if it either does not find a match or the internal map is simply empty.

This can be done by returning 0 in case it can't find a match.

For example:

```
  occurrences(word) {
    let returnValue=this.map1.get(word)!=undefined ? this.map1.get(word) : 0;
    return returnValue;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Though the test text asserts `Counter.occurrences` is case insensitive, it's not. Check the value of `counter.occurrences("Lorem")`, and you'll get 1. In short, the test is doing its job of alerting you to a bug.

Nowhere in `Counter` is case-insensitive matching implemented. Do so, and the test will clear. How to implement case-insensitivity is left as an exercise, especially as this appears to be an assignment.

Note you should also have a test that asserts other cases, e.g. `expect(counter.occurrences("Lorem")).toBe(1);`